# Asterisk ACL Doesn't Seem To Work

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to get Asterisk to allow inbound calls (authed purely on IP) on multiple IPs from the same supplier. The only way that works so far is to create a new sip.conf peer entry for each IP.

ACLs look like they should work, but I cannot work out how to use them properly. That or they don't work as I think they do/should.

For example, if I create the following in my sip.conf (a little stripped down) :

```
[general]
context=no_default_context_allowed
allowguest=yes
...

[supplier]
type=peer
host=1.1.1.1
context=abc
```

the calls that arrive from 1.1.1.1 go to the context abc as expected. However, if I have a range of IPs (eg 1.1.1.80/28) I would expect something along these lines to work :

```
[supplier]
type=peer
host=dynamic
acl=supplier-acl
context=abc
```

with the acl.conf as :

```
[supplier-acl]
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=1.1.1.80/28
```

From the Asterisk CLI :

```
acl show supplier-acl

ACL: supplier-acl
----------------------------------------
0: deny - 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
1: allow - 1.1.1.80/255.255.255.240
```

which looks correct to me, and sip show peers shows A in the ACL column.

In every case, no matter how I try and configure it, the call goes to the default context unless the host contains the precise IP of the inbound call.

I've tried so many config variations I can't honestly remember them all, so what I'm asking is does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: I'm using Asterisk 13.0.2

Answer (score 2):

ACL restricts the network configuration, but *does not identify the host*.

You will need a separate peer entry per call origin host to ensure that the calls get to the right context.  Just make your `[supplier]` into a template, and then have several `[supplier-srv1]`, `[supplier-srv2]` each with `host=<specific ip>` to distinguish them.

Further Reading
+ https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Named+ACLs
+ http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+sip.conf

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've done which is fine for a few. But I've got potentially hundreds. As you can do it easily on Freeswitch I just assumed Asterisk would (by now) have something similar. Ah well.

Answer (score 1):

acl desighned for something like this

```
[localext]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=supersecret
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=192.168.0.1/24
```

You still need add other mandatory params(minimum realy working is above example)

Comment: This only works if the carrier is using username/secret authorisation. Doesn't work on just IP auth (or if it should do I cant seem to make it).

Comment: If use ip auth you have use host=a.b.c.d and not use secret. For ip auth ACL have no sence at all.

Comment: It seems that Asterisk can't do what I want in this instance. I can have IP auth on a subnet with Freeswitch's version of ACL, so I shall just stick with that.

Comment: Asterisk work ok. Please read carefully what writed above and study sip.conf documents.

Comment: In this particular case, Asterisk won't support what the OP is attempting to do with ACLs. @MichaelV69 has the right answer.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. If set host=ip and permit=ip it work ok, i tested that.